# Moving an object in the opposite direction to the cursor

Tags: graphics, 2d

I am trying to accomplish a simple task using a 2D graphics library called paperscript. I have a grid of dots and I would like to recalculate the position of those dots based on the position of the mouse cursor so that the dot is displaced from it's original position in the opposite direction that the mouse cursor is from the original position, and displaced by a distance that is inversely proportional to the distance of the mouse cursor to the original position. Hopefully this diagram makes it a little clearer:

[image: diagram of intended effect]

I know how to get the current position of the mouse, as well as the position of each dot. What I have been having trouble with, is creating a function that will take those two variables and use it to calculate a new position for each dot that will create the above described effect.

I have a jsfiddle here with what I've created so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/yc62k/247xwh8q/4/

```
function onFrame(event) {

     //Loop through all the dots
     for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     var item = project.activeLayer.children[i];

     //Update the position of the dot based on the mouse position
     ??????

     item.position = new Point(
         (newPosition.x),
         (newPosition.y)
     );
 }
}
```

Can anyone suggest an algorithm I can use in this function to get this effect? Or point me in the direction of the maths I would use to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the old position of the dot is `pDot` and the position of the mouse is `pMouse`, then the direction of movement is

```
dir = pDot - pMouse
```

To establish the desired scale (inversely proportional to the distance), just divide by the squared length. Then, the new position is:

```
pDotNew = pDot + dir * (1.0 / squaredLength(dir))
```

Be careful about how often you update the positions. If you update them very frequently, the points might move very fast. If this is the case, multiply the direction with a small number (between 0 and 1). Ideally, this number should depend on the update interval in order to maintain a consistent movement speed.